# Middle-grade story about kid who becomes a spy and flies a secret hypersonic airplane

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book about 20 years ago.  From what I remember it's about a kid who becomes a spy, and he and his friend end up onboard a secret hypersonic scramjet airplane, the Aurora maybe?  There's also a Russian scramjet, and maybe they were chasing each other?

There are a couple other snippets I remember.  At one point his nerdy friend opens a door by melting the lock with a thermite reaction.  Another time, he's in an armored car with two FBI agents, and someone rams a cement mixer into the windshield and fills the front of the car with cement and kills the agents, but the kid escapes.

Comment: The Agent Cody Banks movie is about that old. Maybe its one of his stories?

Comment: I don't think it's Agent Cody Banks, or Destination London, but has a similar feel.  I've looked through the Alex Rider book summaries, and I don't think it's Alex Rider either.